# Jython: Access singleton Java class (static)

Tags: java, python, static, singleton, jython

I cannot seem to get the syntax quite right for this: I have a Jython script and a Java application loaded into the same JVM (for testing).

I need to access a particular part of the application through a Singleton class from the Jython script. How do I do this?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

The set up is for automated testing, so assume that the Jython script already has access to the classes/classpath of the Java application.

Let's say my Java application has a singleton class some.pkg.MySingleton
.. how do I invoke MySingleton.getInstance() from my Jython script?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to call a method on a class in an already running jvm from a jython script? Can you share some of the code?

Comment: If you check Grinder framework code, you might get some idea. I had used Jython to build a load test framework for our project, which used a Singleton to generate users. I can't find that code now.

Comment: @naikus @vinaynag : See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't this work?

```
from some.pkg import MySingleton

myInstance = MySingleton.getInstance()
```

If that doesn't work, try this: (I'm not sure if this works)

```
mySingletonClass = MySingleton(MySingleton)
myInstance = mySingletonClass.getInstance()
```